# Import Spreadsheet to Datasheet SharePoint with calculating columns

Tags: list, excel, datasheet, export-to-excel

Is there a work around in importing Excel Spreadsheet data (copy and paste) into Datasheets with calculating columns?  For some reason, when I import it, the calculating column doesn't populate and it's a read only datasheet column.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could manually copy the calculated column data from Sharepoint to Excel instead?  (Unless you have so much data that this would be impractical).

Otherwise you could recreate the calculated column in Excel.  The problem with calculated columns is that they need all the columns used in the calculation to be present; when the data is sent to Excel you are losing this calculation since Excel is a different application to Sharepoint.

Comment: I'll try it out the the calculate the Spreadsheet first then upload. I'll post the result.  Thanks.